# How to load JSON data from Azure blob storage into Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-blob-storage, connector

I want to load JSON data from Azure blob storage into Apache Kafka which is then to be loaded into another DB. I have tried to use I was trying to use [Azure Blob Storage Source Connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-azure-blob-storage-sink/current/overview.html) with out writing any python code but I think you will have to write into the blob using the sink connector before reading the source connector if I am not mistaken. What is the best way to load the json data into kafka? My requirement is that kafka will continuously listens to file that is being uploaded to azure blob storage and it will be automatically be stored in Kafka topics.

Comment: What connector did you try? What errors did you get? Otherwise, simply downloading a file from Azure using Python has nothing to do with Kafka, so where are you stuck with that? Once you have the file downloaded, then you can do anything with it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do that:

### Event Based

Create an Azure function which is triggered when a message stored on Blob Storage. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function#:%7E:text=Create%20an%20Azure%20Blob%20storage%20triggered%20function%201,4%20Select%20Create%20Function%20to%20create%20your%20function).

Now as an when message is stored, Azure function is invoked and you can push it to Kafka as following:

```
import json 
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer =KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers='xxxx..x.')

dictionary = {'height':115, 'weight':73, 'size':19}
jsonString = json.dumps(dictionary)
producer.send_message(topic, jsonString .encode('utf-8'))
```

### Batch based

You can also load data to Kafka in batch style by reading messages from blob in a loop and them pushing them to Kafka as shown above. If you are reading from a file containing JSON messages, the perhaps you can do following:

```
with open(filename) as f:
  data = json.load(f)
  producer.send_message(topic, data.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: So, the Kafka needs to be deployed in order to access it from Azure Functions?

Comment: I thought that Kafka broker is already installed. If that is not the case, then yes it needs to be installed. Don't think there is any managed service for Kafka available in Azure but you can install it though HDInsight. 

*But in my opinion if you are dependent on Kafka and is looking for any streaming solution, better is to go with **Azure Event Hub** in Azure*

Comment: No, it was not installed. I was using Kafka locally. Is there any way to access Azure functions locally? Sorry, I am new to this thing.

Comment: I haven't tried to be honest but seems like there is way. Please try this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local